# PHP: Incorrect JSON decoding and stripslashes \t \n

Tags: php, json, stripslashes, magic-quotes-gpc

I think in server that I'm working, magic_quotes are active and when receive a json from jquery.ajax I do this:

```
alcancesP = stripslashes($_POST['alcances']);
```

After I decode alcancesP:

```
$dataAlcances = json_decode(alcancesP,true);
```

But when I pass **$dataAlcances** to foreach, '\' disapear but T and N don't.

**This is alcances Post**

```
alcances    [{"marca":"4","marcatxt":"\n\t\tCitrix\t\t\t","producto":"2","productotxt":"Networking","subproducto":"2","subproductotxt":"Netscaler"},{"marca":"8","marcatxt":"\n\t\tCoca Cola Company\t\t\t","producto":"8","productotxt":"Del Valle","subproducto":"5","subproductotxt":"Valle Frut"}]
```

And when I save this data in a table, insert like this:

```
nttCitrixttt             |     Networking     |    Netscaler
nttCoca Cola Companyttt  |    Del Valle       |    Valle Frut
```

I want remove N and T to save correctly.

Unfortunately I have no access to the server to modify the php.ini and disable magic quotes.

I hope can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you `stripslashes`ing?

Comment: Because if don't apply stripslashes, when decode json, doesn't work, only in server but in local work without problem if don't apply stripslashes

Answer (score 0):

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$str = str_replace(array('\t','\n'),'',$str);
```

Or [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\\\\n|\\\\t)/', '', $str);
```